# generating javadoc as a word document

Tags: java, javadoc

How can we generate javadoc as a word document instead of the traditional html pages?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

look into doclets, http://doclet.com which have plenty of examples of custom javadoc rendering (i.e into PDF's etc...) and also look into Apache POI (http://poi.apache.org/) for the generation of MS Office files

Answer (score 4):

If you could live with pdf instead of word, you should give [PDFDoclet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfdoclet/) a chance. I discovered it on doclet.com (thanks to Mark for the link). It works quite well, is easy use and allows some configuration. For my purpose, pdf is better suited than word because a  pdf document is better suited for reading than a word in regard to the needed viewer application.

Here is my small windows batch file:

```
echo OFF

set JAVA_HOME=C:/program files/Java/jdk1.6.0_23
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%/bin;%PATH%
set VERSION=1.0.2
set DOCLET=com.tarsec.javadoc.pdfdoclet.PDFDoclet
set JARS=jar/pdfdoclet-%VERSION%-all.jar
set PACKAGE="cvu.html"

javadoc -doclet %DOCLET% -docletpath %JARS% -pdf html.pdf -config example/html/config_html.properties -private -sourcepath example/html -subpackges %PACKAGE%
```

Comment: well, yeah surely. My point is: choose the right tool for the job. for pdf exists several relativly small reader while word demands a rather bloated editor just for reading a javadoc document. I will update my answer to clearify my thought.

Comment: You're batch file has a typo on the -subpackages parameter

Comment: thank you, PDFDoclet does the job very well, and easy to lauch in Eclipse Project > Generate javadoc. If necessary, the output PDF can always be converted in word, I personnaly use All PDF Converter Pro, it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

http://doclet.com/ links an RTF Doclet ("RTF Doclet generates RTF format documentation.")
The resulting RTF opens in Word and Open Office Writer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use maven to run the [pdfdoclet](http://pdfdoclet.sourceforge.net/). Though I did not find any "official" maven repository the following seems more clear to me, opposed to fiddling with shell scripts or using ant-commands in maven as proposed on their [website](http://pdfdoclet.sourceforge.net/running.html):

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>

            <configuration>
                <doclet>com.tarsec.javadoc.pdfdoclet.PDFDoclet</doclet>
                <docletPath>path/to/pdfdoclet-1.0.2-all.jar</docletPath>
                <useStandardDocletOptions>false</useStandardDocletOptions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Note the disabling of the standard options, otherwise javadoc complains of unknown options (apparently not supported by the pdfdoclet)

From there you can start customizing, using the ever-concise [maven documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/examples/alternate-doclet.html)