# Tools to generate JavaDoc in DOC or RTF format?

Tags: javadoc, rtf, .doc

Are there any free tools available that can generate JavaDoc in `.doc` or `.rtf` or `.pdf` (I can live with pdf too) format rather than HTML??

I am using NetBeans and it generates a very neat and clean javadoc as html and css, but I want to put them in an MS Word document. It has approx 50 html documents, its not feasible to copy-paste it on document file, also if I copy-paste it than I lost the formatting created throughh CSS by NetBeans. Any Solutions? Plugins? Software?

Comment: Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606255/generating-javadoc-as-a-word-document